# How to fix "dl failure" / "invalid ELF header" error while installing MATLAB?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I tried installing MATLAB R2013a with this command:

```
sudo ./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

And I got this massege:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_2573/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m  -splash:"/home/yair/Matinstall/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_2573/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jar/ja_JP/:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jar/zh_CN/:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_2573/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/yair/Matinstall" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_2573" 
Error: dl failure on line 864
Error: failed /tmp/mathworks_2573/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, because /tmp/mathworks_2573/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header
Finished
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: did you install "libstdc++6.x.x-dev" and "matlab-support" packages?

Comment: I installed libstdc++6-4.4-dev but it didnt help

Comment: To install matlab-support package it asks you to have an installed matlab on your computer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant but look here: http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/49397-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libstdc-so-6-invalid-ELF-header